# Github Master repository changes

Tags: github

I'm pretty new to github and have a few questions.

I forked a repository and commited some changes to it. When the master repository gets updated or somethling like this, do i get these updates to? Or do i have to merge them manually?

Comment: You mean, you adding to the original repo your changes. Or get the changes that make it to the original repo?

Comment: I mean i wanna add the changes which where made on the master since i forked it.

Answer (score 2):

You must do it manually but remember to add the `upstream` repository (the one that you forked).

```
cd path/you/forked/repo
git checkout master
git remote add upstream git@github.com:user/original_repo
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

at this point you have both `origin` (which points to your github repository) and `upstream` that point to the repository that you forked.

If you made some changes to your `master` branch and did not submit a pull request then it will be treated as a regular merge. This means that commits in `upstream/master` will merge with commits in your `master` branch.

If those changes conflict with upcoming changes then you must manually resolve the conflicts or apply [merge strategy](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) If a file that i changed got updated in upstream, can i decide which one i want? or do i have to do my changes again?

Answer (score 0):

You have tto do it manually. Create a pull request.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what he's asking - I think he's wondering about updating his own fork to reflect the state of the updated master.